# URL path meaning in Tomcat

Tags: url, tomcat

I deployed an application named "am" on Apache Tomcat7.
When I point the browser to that application (http://x.server.com:8080/am), in the address bar immediately appears this URL: http://x.server.com:8080/am/task/Home, thus the sub-path "/task/Home" is added.

The strange thing is that on the server I cannot find any path /am/task/Home in the tomcat7 locations. 
Shouldn't an URL path always reflect a directory path on a machine?

Answer (score 0):

Not always.  The URL is independent of the file system (although you can set it up in your container to reflect it).  Try looking at your `web.xml` file to see how the `<servlet-mapping>` elements are mapping URLs to your serlvets.